# Debian buster odd IFace issue

Tags: debian, network-interface

i've been taking some tome to learn more about Linux, and i've chosen Debian buster as mais main 'lab'. One think to highlit is: its a debian vm on Oracle virtual box.

The problem is: i want to work with an static ip, but though ive configured everything accordingly to my network parameter, the if won't come up. (check journalctl -xe, and it brings a failure message) Check it bellow:

[image]

I'm using Oracle vbox with the network set as 'bridge'. Under dhcp it works just fine.

Some help would be much appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: Welcome! `adress` is mispelled, it's `address`.

Comment: Hello. Please [don't post pictures of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/100397). Also, where you write, "_check journalctl -xe, and it brings a failure message_" please do [show us](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/581878/edit) the (exact) error message.

Comment: @guillermochamorro That's right! Another "d" was missing. Thanks pal!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the support. The problem was a missing 'd' at the address line.

Answer (score 0):

network line is wrong, remove it completely (correct is 192.168.1.0, but it's not necessary)

broadcast line is wrong, remove it completely (correct is 192.168.1.255, but it's not necessary)

Crucial: How have you setup networking in Virtualbox for the VM? Using the default options, you'll not have network using these static IP settings. It would be easier to revert to switch to dhcp.

Comment: I've chosen a static ip scenario just for study purposes ;) A 'd' was missing at the address line.